# Why isn't centered being applied on modal

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-modal, react-bootstrap

I am trying to create a modal for confirmation of logout, and I'm trying to keep the modal at the center of the screen. It is getting center aligned, but vertically it isn't center.

Here's what I've tried:

```
    <Modal
      show={true}
      centered
      aria-labelledby="example-custom-modal-styling-title"
    >
      <Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Title>{t("common.logout")}</Modal.Title>
      </Modal.Header>
      <Modal.Body>{t("logout.message")}</Modal.Body>
      <Modal.Footer>
        <Button variant="secondary" onClick={() => handleCloseLogout()}>
          {t("common.no")}
        </Button>
        <Button className="btn-primary" onClick={() => handleLogoutYes()}>
          {t("common.yes")}
        </Button>
      </Modal.Footer>
    </Modal>
```

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: The code that you provided does not highlight the issue. Your code is correct. Please check if you've some conflicting styles. Or you can try to replicate the issue on https://codesandbox.io/ and share it with us.